# After resizing a image, the image will increase the file size

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the library Resizer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer) to resize images, however the new image's file size increases after resizing. How do I make my files smaller?

```
import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";
export const resizeFile = (file, width = 900, height = 900) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(file);
    const filename = file.name;
    const fileExt = filename.split(".").pop();
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      file,
      width,
      height,
      fileExt,
      50,
      0,
      uri => {
        console.log(uri);
        resolve(uri);
      },
      "file"
    );
  });
```

```
image = await resizeFile(fileUpload);
onsole.log(image);
```

The result:
[image]

This is the image i'm using
[image]

I tried lowering the image quality from 100 to 50, but it had no effect.

Comment: Your original image is encoded with IJG quality 70 and default quantisation tables scaled by 0.6x. It is also encoded as a progressive JPEG using SOF2. I suspect your resaved one is taking a hit from the resampling artefacts and being saved as a normal default JPEG. If you put up a sample of the saved one at say size 64x64 using your original code it should be possible to work out what is going wrong from the headers. Awkward sampling ratios and mangling the aspect ratio to make it square will each add artefacts. Try to make the new horizontal length a multiple of 16 if you can..

Answer (score 0):

The increase in size may be due to the quality setting you are using in the `Resizer.imageFileResizer` function. In your code, you have set the quality to `50`, which may result in a large file size.

Here's an updated version of your `resizeFile` function with a lower quality setting (for example, 30) to potentially reduce the file size:

```
import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";

export const resizeFile = (file, width = 900, height = 900) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const filename = file.name;
    const fileExt = filename.split(".").pop();
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      file,
      width,
      height,
      fileExt,
      30, // Lower quality to reduce file size
      0,
      uri => {
        resolve(uri);
      },
      "file"
    );
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried with quality = `10` but it is still not addressed.